# Output of top command contains weird characters

Tags: linux

I have a file in linux which contains the result of the `top -c` command. I'm about to send the file to my email address. When opening it, it is showing some special unknown characters:

```
^[[?1h^[=^[[?25l^[[H^[[2J^[(B^[[mtop - 12:23:27 up 1 day,  1:36,  4 users,
```

How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

Usually `top` will output terminal control characters in order to update the screen. You can suppress them using the `-b` option. It will start `top` in batch mode. `-n1` means only one iteration:

```
top -cbn1 > output.file
```